# Accessing Public Class Function in Private Class Giving Error

Tags: c++

```
class test
{
private:
    class privateStruct
    {
    public:
        int m;
        privateStruct(int p){m=p;}
    };
};

void ff()
{
    test::privateStruct ps(4);
    throw ps; //Does not work.. 
}

void main()
{
    try
    {
        ff();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
}
```

But the Following Code Works Why

```
class test
{
private:
    class privateStruct
    {
    public:
        int m;
        privateStruct(int p){m=p;}
    };
};

void ff()
{
    throw test::privateStruct(4); //Work why
}

void main()
{
    try
    {
        ff();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
}
```

**NOTE : I am using VC++ 6.**

I need answer why the above code works.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Using which compiler does the second example "work?" Both Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 and Intel C++ Compiler 11 for Windows fail to compile it because `privateStruct` is inaccessible.

Comment: I'll add that gcc4.4 also won't compile either of those, for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old/known bug with Visual Studio 6.0. It ignores access specifiers when constructing temporaries. No fix is available.

Raising the warning level to 3 or higher (/W3) will cause the offending code to give a warning.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your second example works because Visual C++ 6 is notorious for its horrible standards compliance.

It works by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Even the second code snippet won't compile. privateStruct cannot be accessed in the function ff().